# How can I let Typescript know, that my function will clone a passed Readonly protected argument?

Tags: typescript, clone, readonly

I'd like to know how I can make Typescript understand, that *update* can be mutated by the function which is passed as the second parameter to modifyState because *update* will be cloned.

```
// Basic example
import { clone } from 'lodash';

interface IState {
  foo: string;
}

const state: Readonly<IState> = {
  foo: "bar"
};

// Start situation
function modifyState<S>(
  prevState: S,
  updateFunc: (update: S) => void
): S {
  const newState = clone(prevState);
  updateFunc(newState);
  return newState;
}

modifyState(
  state,
  update => {
    update.foo = "another string"; // 'Cannot assign to 'foo' because it is a constant or a read-only property.'
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could infer the generic type from the generic type parameter of the received `Readonly<T>` value instead:

```
function modifyState<S>(
    prevState: Readonly<S>, // <- this one
    updateFunc: (update: S) => void
): Readonly<S> {
    ...
}
```

I believe the code is self-explanatory. If you need to support both `readonly` and non-readonly versions, you could use an overload signature, or a union type, such as:

```
prevState: Readonly<S> | S
```

In this case, the TypeScript compiler will *prefer* `Readonly<S>` over `S`, when applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

```
type Mutable<T extends { [x: string]: any }, K extends string> = {
    [P in K]: T[P];
}

...
updateFunc: (update: Mutable<S, keyof S>) => void
```

([code in playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%2F%2F%20Basic%20example%0D%0Aimport%20%7B%20clone%20%7D%20from%20'lodash'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Mutable%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20%5Bx%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%20%7D%2C%20K%20extends%20string%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20K%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IState%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20state%3A%20Readonly%3CIState%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20foo%3A%20%22bar%22%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Start%20situation%0D%0Afunction%20modifyState%3CS%3E(%0D%0A%20%20prevState%3A%20S%2C%0D%0A%20%20updateFunc%3A%20(update%3A%20Mutable%3CS%2C%20keyof%20S%3E)%20%3D%3E%20void%0D%0A)%3A%20S%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20newState%20%3D%20clone(prevState)%3B%0D%0A%20%20updateFunc(newState)%3B%0D%0A%20%20return%20newState%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AmodifyState(%0D%0A%20%20state%2C%0D%0A%20%20update%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20update.foo%20%3D%20%22another%20string%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A)%3B))

As explained here: [Mapped Types syntax to remove modifiers](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13723).